# How to find the average of a row in pandas barring one column?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-cleaning

I'm trying to find the average of each row without taking into account the "unnamed column" which is the year.
Currently I have:

```
print(df.mean(axis=0))
```

But this just finds the average WITH the year which obviously is a huge outlier and skews the data.

Below is the dataset I am using:

[image]

Comment: Could I make the years into strings which could also help me when I'm trying to make a line plot?

Comment: I think you should load file with `pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', index_col=0)` to define the first col as the index.

Comment: But Corralien, what if I wanted to make a line plot (years as the x-axis and yearly average as the y axis)?

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding the first column with `.loc`:

```
print(df.iloc[:, 1:].mean(axis=0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[[col for col in df.col if 'Unnamed' not in col]].mean(axis=0)
```